# Why aws s3 sync <source> <target> --delete doesn't delete folder that is in the target folder and not on the source folder

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Please I would like to know:

Why aws s3 sync   --delete doesn't delete folder that is in the target folder and not on the source folder?

Here an example:

I use the following command on the aws cli to sync the 2 buckets:

```
aws s3 sync \
    "s3://sourcebucket-us-east-1/test_copy_data/" \
    "s3://targetbucket-us-east-1/test_copy_data/" \
    --delete
```

In the `s3://targetbucket-us-east-1/test_copy_data/` folder there is a file `s3://targetbucket-us-east-1/test_copy_data/folder1/file1.txt` that doesn't exist in the source folder `s3://sourcebucket-us-east-1/test_copy_data/`.

When I launch the command, `s3://targetbucket-us-east-1/test_copy_data/folder1/file1.txt` are deleted but s3://targetbucket-us-east-1/test_copy_data/folder1/` is still there and empty

Thank you

Comment: Can you give us a minimum reproducible example?

Comment: Thank, yes, i edited the description with an example

Comment: The `--delete` option is described thus: "Files that exist in the destination but not in the source are deleted during sync". Conceivably, the s3 sync command is only designed to delete file-like objects, not folder-like objects such as `test_copy_data/folder1/`.

Comment: Thank you for your help i appreciate . I understand. Please, do you know by chance how can i achive this goal?

Comment: One obvious way would be to purge the target location first and then sync source to target, but that's not ideal. You might also raise an [awscli issue](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli) to understand why the behavior is the way it is.

Comment: You have an empty source folder right? Delete the folder locally and then check to see if the CLI deletes the folder in S3 as well or not.

Comment: I have the same issue, works with individual files but not directories :/

Comment: Thank you all for your help, I really appreciate, i will test and evaluate the suggestions you gave.